# How to fix: mac keyboard ignores "first" key pressed

Tags: mac, keyboard, macbook

**UPDATE *2012.03.19*:** the MBP described in this post is now broken and recycled (logic board fried). The replacement doesn't manifest the same problems. I tend to believe the problem originated in the keyboard firmware of the old MBP.

---

Every now and then, usually after I haven't pressed a key in some time, sometimes minutes, sometimes seconds, my MBP will "swallow" the the first key I press ...

say I'm logging into "superuser.com" .. I start typing my username and the textbox will show "exu" instead of "lexu"

This is driving me nuts!

My guess is the keyboard or it's controller goes to sleep and fails to wake up propperly ...

**What can I do about this?**

PS: I've already installed "[MacBook, MacBook Pro Keyboard Firmware Update 1.0](http://support.apple.com/downloads/MacBook__MacBook_Pro_Keyboard_Firmware_Update_1_0)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a thread discussing a problem that sounds very similar, but no solution.  One commenter said that they experienced this problem with the laptop keyboard, but an external keyboard's first keypress was never ignored.  Not exactly a solution, but at least a workaround.

http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1538675

Comment: I've started using an external keyboard when working at home...

Answer (score 0):

try disabling "Ignore accidental track pad input" in system preferences - worked for me.

Comment: Ooh, I'm going to try that when my MBP comes back from having its NVIDIA borkage repaired. So far I've ended up going for an external keyboard, but it doesn't help when I'm actually using it as a laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Bet you're using KeyClick.
After switching it off I get every first key press…

Comment: No I wasn't :-) The question is obsolete, the MBP has been replaced.